# Pass a couple of values in RadioGroup

Tags: react-native

Used react-native-flexi-radio-button https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-flexi-radio-button for radio buttons which is awesome but wondering if other values can be passed like index and value props.

For instance Here we can get the selected index and selected value. But I wonder whether I can pass other props (like id from json below) to the radioGroup as well too. I want to pass the id as well. How can I do that?

```
onSelect(index, value) {
    console.log('selected index and value', index + value);
}

<View style={styles.border}>
    <RadioGroup
      onSelect={(index, value) => this.onSelect(index, value)}
    >
      {this.state.foodList.map(item1 => {
        return (
          <RadioButton value={item1.food}>
            <Text>{item1.food}</Text>
          </RadioButton>
        );
      })}
    </RadioGroup>
</View>
```

Json data

```
{"foodList": [
    {
      "id": 40,
      "food": "Bagels",
    },
    {
      "id": 27,
      "food": "Beverage",
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "food": "Burger",
    }
]}
```

Comment: have you tried passing an object instead?  <RadioButton value={item1}>

Comment: You can use the index to get the id value inside the onSelect callback function.  this.state.foodList[index].id

Comment: thankyou both of you for the wonderful ideas. You guys are great...